# Set Theory Union and Complement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question and I am stuck on for a while
I need to prove or disprove that
if $A \cup B=A \setminus B$ then $B=\emptyset$.

I actually don't know where to start. It's obvious when drawing it but I need a full proof.

How can I do it?

Thanks...

Comment: All elements of $B$ are in $A\cup B$, and none of them are in $A\setminus B$. So if $A\cup B=A\setminus B$, then "all elements of $B$" must agree with "none of the elements of $B$." That happens only if $B$ has no elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $x\in B$. Then $x\in B\cup A=A\setminus B$, so $x\not\in B$, a contradiction.